# Get value of string before the prototype

Tags: javascript, string, prototype

I currently have a String.protype called isColor, which is checking the color.
But i dont want it to have an argument inside the function.

I want to archive something like this:

```js
const color = 'red';

console.log(color.isColor());
```

expected output:
`true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the method, compare the `this` (the instance) against whatever you're comparing it against:

```js
String.prototype.isColor = function() {
  return ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'].includes(String(this));
}
console.log('red'.isColor());
console.log('somethingElse'.isColor());
```

You need the `String` to convert the `this` if you run the script in sloppy mode, in which case `this` will be a string *object*, not a string *primitive*, so you need to turn it into a primitive before comparison.

But keep in mind that mutating built-in prototypes is [*very* bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) - you should strongly consider using a different approach, if at all possible.